# Make clear the relationship between dynamic checkbox and other components

Tags: usability, checkboxes

I have a dialog,as a below. In a dialog you can choose a state, mark it as "like / not like", and write a comment. In dropdown box for states you can also choose an option "All states". Then comment and checkbox value will be saved for all states.

My question how to make it clear that it will be saved only currently selected state option. I dont't whant that user change to Alabama write a comment "good option"  then changes to Alaska writes "so cold", clicks ok, and think Alabama and Alaska comments was  changed. (Only Alaska comment will be changed).

What can be made to make the behaviour clearer ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If comment area and action buttons are disabled during selecting the state from drop-down,  you can have the explained behavior. You can create less than 1 sec waiting time to activate the comment area, this will create a connection between drop down and the rest of the elements.

I think that it can be nice if you can use a visual element for selecting state if it is about traveling context.

Comment: http://freehtml5maps.com/free-html5-usa-map/  just think about it

Comment: Thank you, this is not about traveling. In reality it is laguages)

Comment: @Tony My pleasure, success with your design